# What does $\sum_{j=1}^{n} {n \choose j}(-1)^jx_{t-j}$ mean?

Tags: combinatorics

I have no combinatorics assignment, I just try to understand time series where author suddenly uses this notation. $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} {n \choose j} (-1)^jx_{t-j}$$

Let n=2 for simplicity. I think that obvious to do is to assign this coefficients $ {n \choose j}$ from bottom to top:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n=2} {n \choose j} (-1)^jx_{t-j} = 1  (-1)^1 x_{t-1} + 2 (-1)^2 x_{t-2}$$
But this is nonsense. Then how should I use it?

Comment: Yep, I confused, the answer was simple =( Please right this as solution, soI give you up vote.

Comment: "But this is nonsense": what's nonsense in this expression, which by the way is $-2x_{t-1}+x_{t-2}$ for $n=2$.

Comment: You seem to know what $n\choose j$ means, so why are you asking what it is in the title?

Comment: I did not know that. I supposed that this is kind of coefficient assignment. But then people told me that this is combination stuff.

Comment: I fixed the misleading title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big sum operator is expanded as a linear sum where you replace the dummy index by all values in the allowed range.

Hence,

$$\sum_{j=1}^{2} {2 \choose j} (-1)^jx_{t-j}= {2 \choose 1}(-1)^1x_{t-1}+ {2 \choose 2}(-1)^2x_{t-2},$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{3} {3 \choose j} (-1)^jx_{t-j}= {3 \choose 1}(-1)^1x_{t-1}+ {3 \choose 2}(-1)^2x_{t-2}+ {3 \choose 3}(-1)^3x_{t-3},\\\cdots$$
You can lookup the coefficients in Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is another symbol for the combinations i.e. say n choose 2, number of ways to choose 2 objects from n objects without repetition and the order of selection does not matter, i.e. 123 is same as 321 or 213 however they are not the same as permutation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination